# How should I map relationships between multiple inheritance models?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, relation

I have an Eentity Framework model with a **Table Per Hierarchy** (Brand) and also a **Table Per Type** (Vehicle) inheritance like this:

[image]

(Vehicle and Brand are abstract classes).

So far so good, I can access derived entities on linq queries using `Vehicle.OfType<>` or `Brand.OfType<>` method.

Now, Brand entity is one to many related with Vehicle on my conceptual model, So the question is, how should I make relationships on EF model so I can keep using navigation properties between Vehicle and Brand but at the same time keep the consistency of the TPH inheritance on Brand?, my first approach was to relate only derived clases, like:

[image]

But if I do this, I have no access to Brand directly from Vehicle, so I would have to do a double relation (between derived and base), like:

[image]

This works for me now, but I still have a duplicated relationship somehow, is this right?, do you have a better approach?, am I'm making some silly mistake on my modelling?

Comment: Devil's advocate question: What kind of brand is Honda? IMHO, you're over-using inheritance here.

Comment: I know there are brands that have both (cars and motorcycles) but in that case we want to differentiate them as "Honda Car" and "Honda Bykes", is that why you think is a over-using?

Comment: Because an object can only ever have one type. Even if you think this is right for Honda, it won't be right for every brand everywhere. Using type as a flag for a single business attribute like that backs you into a corner where it's hard to evolve your schema. I would model this as an association: [Brand: Honda] is related to [CarBrand: HondaCars] (i.e., 2 instances instead of a hierarchy). Then you could just change the cardinality from 1:1 to 1:* if you wanted to have a brand which could contain both.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the reason you are running into cross-linking in your model is because you are artificially separating **Brand** and **Vehicle** as top-level sibling entities. If you start with **Brand**, which seems essentially equivalent to **Make**, that becomes the true top-level entity. There is no need to separate **Make** for each vehicle type (car, motorcycle, truck, etc.); just introduce the entity **Model** between **Make** and **Vehicle** and I think that solves most of your cross-linking problems.

Then the relationships aren't strictly parent-child, but are more accurate as composition. So you have **Make**, which has a one-to-many composite relationship to **Model**, which in turn has a one-to-many composite relationship to **Vehicle**. Vehicles are *instances* of a **Model**, so there isn't really a parent-child relationship there either. With this structure, there is no need to branch the EF for each type of **Vehicle**, because that is just part of what is described by the **Model** entity.

I hope my answer is helpful and that I haven't missed any of the essential points of what you are trying to model-